# Getting *NoSuchMethodException* when method definitely is part of the class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, reflection, invoke

I have the following class:

```kotlin
class CountryDataItem (
    id: Long?, 
    private val countryName :String?, 
    private var countryFlagUrl : String?,
    var gameCount : Int,  
    var liveCount:Int
) : BaseDataItem(id) {
    
    companion object {
        
        fun onCreateViewHolder(
            parent: ViewGroup,
            onRecyclerItemClickListener: OnRecyclerItemClickListener?
        ): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            val view: View =
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.country_item, parent, false);
        }
    }
}
```

But when running:

```kotlin
someKClass.java.getMethod(
    "onCreateViewHolder",
    parent.javaClass,
    onRecyclerItemClickListenerRef.get()?.javaClass
)
```

I'm getting the exception.
Can't understand why
I even used the method : *getMethods* to get a list with the names of all the methods in the class, and the method exist. It means i'm sending a wrong parameter (but cannot figure out what is wrong)
Attachment List:

[image]

Additional Info:
The second argument i'm sending to *getMethod* is a WeakReference that conceal inside him a instance that is from type *AllScoresFragment* and also **implements** the interface *OnRecyclerItemClickListener*, but when i'm running the *getMethod* method with :

```
onRecyclerItemClickListenerRef.get()?.javaClass
```

, the result is *AllScoresFragment* type and not *OnRecyclerItemClickListener* type. Therefore he can't find the method and throws an exception.
Trying to cast the object before sending it:
val castedVariable  = `onRecyclerItemClickListenerRef.get() as? OnRecyclerItemClickListener`

and then sending it as:

```
castedVariable.javaClass
```

doesn't help.
Maybe someone  can give me an idea how to overcome the problem?

Comment: Is there anything else in the stacktrace?

Comment: It seems that stack track is long because of there are a lot of method but it seems that the root cause is : *2020-11-29 16:57:22.891 21061-21061/com.example.todeleteimmediatley E/123456: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.allScoresScreen.dataItems.CountryDataItem.onCreateViewHolder [class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView, class com.example.allScoresScreen.AllScoresFragment]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a companion object in a class Kotlin is equivalent to creating a static final class within a class in Java. So, the method defined in the companion object is not equivalent to a static method within a class in Java and cannot be accessed as you have tried to. Try this:

```kotlin
import kotlin.reflect.full.companionObject

someKClass.companionObject?.java?.getMethod(
    "onCreateViewHolder", 
    ViewGroup::class.java,
    OnRecyclerItemClickListener::class.java
)
```

If the import is not found add the kotlin-reflect library.

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.4.20"
```

Comment: you are the second person who tell me to put *.conpanionObject* after a *KClass* instance but it is not available to *KClass* (unresolved)

Comment: there isn't suitable import... Did you lock at the picture i have attached.. Can't understand why, but both methods: *onCreateViewHolder* and *onBindViewHolder* path looks totally different

Comment: Yes I'm. maybe because i have a KClass<out BaseDataItem>?  when debugger doesn't enable me to debug *getMethod*

Comment: I treid to make my life a little easier (really hate Kotlin), and get rid of the companion and put the method as part of the class. Now of course i'm getting the method in the list, but when trying to get the method via: **someKClass.java.getMethod(
    "onCreateViewHolder",
    parent.javaClass,
    onRecyclerItemClickListenerRef.get()?.javaClass
)**    I'm still get the same exceptions. Maybe now arguments are wrong but how can i know for sure? everything looks ok and it still not work. What process can help me here? I want to step into getMethod with debugger but i always step over

Comment: thanks a lot !!! but i realize another point that cause the exception. Maybe it will now be easy to help me. I really hope you will still have enough power to look on my edited post

Comment: i thought it  is smarter to use instance and not "hard coded". Can you (maybe) tell why my cast in the post isn't being counted?

Comment: I did exactly what you said and still got:
**2020-11-29 16:57:22.891 21061-21061/com.example.todeleteimmediatley E/123456: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.allScoresScreen.dataItems.CountryDataItem.onCreateViewHolder [class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView, class com.example.allScoresScreen.AllScoresFragment]**
If you want to help in the chat i will be happy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225286/discussion-between-kyzer-soze-and-eitanos30).

Comment: sorry for bothering but maybe you can answer my question because i didn't find an answer for it. Why did you consisted that i will use
 **ViewGroup::class.java,OnRecyclerItemClickListener::class.java** and not **parent.javaClass,onRecyclerItemClickListener.javaclass**.. I see that in "my way" it doesn't work.. but i can understand why. It seems exactly the same solution since both way returns a Class<?>

Comment: Because let's say a class implements an interface, for example, a fragment class extends `onRecyclerItemClickListener`. Now if you use `parent.javaClass` you will the fragment class when you actually need `onRecyclerItemClickListener`

Comment: I understand. But why did you mention *parent.javaClass* if the issue is related to *onRecyclerItemClickListener*? In addition, why the casting i have made: *val castedVariable = onRecyclerItemClickListenerRef.get() as? OnRecyclerItemClickListener* didn't help here?*

Comment: because u are using `parent.javaClass` in your code. Regarding the second question, why dont you just debug and check these simple things??

Comment: @Kyszr Soze, i have tried to debug but i can't debug *getMethod*, so i can't get any conclusion. I will try again but please don't answer me like i am a lazy one, try to understand that if i am asking it's always after i fail to understand after along fight. BTW, the IDE says this cast it redundant. Thanks again

Comment: i'm trying to debug. I'm trying everything. Although I'm writing directly that i want a *OnRecyclerItemClickListener* variable: 
*val castedVariable : OnRecyclerItemClickListener? = onRecyclerItemClickListenerRef.get() as? OnRecyclerItemClickListener*
When debugging the variable type remains *AllScoresFragment*. It's killing me.. I will try to write a new question with this situation.. Maybe the answer is simpler than i think

Comment: That is what is expected. [Example](https://pl.kotl.in/jaThjKp_j)